# Using a function as an argument of another function and execute it in each loop

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have several functions in R that get me vectors with different random results, let's call these functions r1, r2, r3 and r4.

Now I want to write another function named 'simulation' that simulates one of these functions above and evaluates different values like the expected value etc. 
Furthermore, I want only one function that can simulate either r1, r2, r3 or r4, which is possible, because they all put out the same type of vector.

I have tried it by the following way:

```
simulation <- function(f, n) {
  result <- 0
  for (i in 1:n) {
    result <- result + f[1]
  }
  result
}
```

Then I execute it like this: 
    simulation(r1(), 500)

This works fine, but the problem is that the function r1() just runs once, but as I want to simulate it n times, I want it to run each time I go through the for-loop.

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the function itself instead of its return value :

```
simulation(r1, 500)
```

But then you have to modify the code :

```
result <- result + f()[1]
```

Comment: Wow, did not expect that it would be that easy. Thank you!